# Sudoku Solver Recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I encountered this problem while solving a leetcode problem (https://leetcode.com/problems/sudoku-solver/).

The problem states like that:

> Write a program to solve a Sudoku puzzle by filling the empty cells.
>
> Empty cells are indicated by the character '.'.
>
> You may assume that there will be only one unique solution.

My solution is

```
public class Solution {
    public void solveSudoku(char[][] board) {
        helper(board, 0, 0);
    }   


    //recursion body
    public boolean helper(char[][] board, int row, int col){
    
        //In the two for loop, if I change i = row and j = col to i = 0 and j = 0
        //respectively, the program returns the right answer.
        for(int i = row; i < 9 ; ++i){
            for(int j = col; j < 9; ++j){
                if(board[i][j] == '.'){
                    for(char ch = '1'; ch <= '9'; ch++){
                        if(check(board, i, j, ch)){
                            board[i][j] = ch;
                            if(helper(board, i, j)){
                                return true;
                            }else{
                            board[i][j] = '.';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    return true;
}

    //check if the character to be filled is right.
    public boolean check(char[][] board, int row, int col, char ch){
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i){
            if(board[row][i] == ch){
                return false;
            }
            if(board[i][col] == ch){
                return false;
            }
        }
        for(int i = row / 3 * 3; i < row / 3 * 3+ 3; ++i){
            for(int j = col / 3 * 3; j < col / 3 * 3 + 3; ++j){
                if(board[i][j] == ch){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

That piece of code does not pass the OJ, but if I change the first two for loops in helper function to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 9 ; ++i){
    for(int j = 0; j < 9; ++j){
    ...
    }
}
```

That works. I am really puzzled by that. since in the for loops, before i and j comes to row and col, the function actually does nothing other than iterating the values. Could someone tell me why this make a difference?

I read a lot of articles about recursion but I'm still not sure about the problem, could someone help me?

Comment: Put some debug in to print `i` and `j`, and what you're doing with them.

Comment: Good point, I did that and found the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I print i and j under the two for loops and found that the problem is because if I call helper(i, j) each time. the value of j can only increase, it can not be decreased.